# Factory Reset, lost grub, never upgraded from 12.0.4

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, grub2, windows-7

Windows 7 partition difficulties due to anti-virus problems. Slow boot, could not shutdown without power down

Have separate partition with Ubuntu GNOME 12.0.4.

Tries to restore Win 7 from boot. Didn't work after days of trials. Restored factory settings. Grub erased.

Trying to restore Grub via memory stick. Question is ... if I download 14 LT desktop for boot, is the 12.0.4 upwards compatible or should I boot from a 12.0.4 mem stick boot image and then perform a full 14 upgrade? Where would I obtain the Ubuntu 12.0.4 image (I do not have CDs). Attemps to download from alternate versions within windows does not successfully download (torrent or network). I cannot lose the data on the Ubuntu 12.0.4 partition ... it is the backup partition for all my documents and the Win 7 factory restore wiped out the originals.

I have a YouTube tutorial but it assumes Ubuntu 14 desktop as the image source.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Because there can be different versions of grub in different version of Ubuntu, it is better to use the same Grub as in the original installation, in your case 12.04. You can get the 12.04 ISO image for your system by going [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/) and burn it to a USB using tools such as [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). Once you have that you can follow the instructions in [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) or in [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing) article to re-install grub

Comment: I was able to successfully accomplish this yesterday before your response. I had a problem with os-prober, but when I ran it manually once, all the grub.d scripts worked correctly so I am back.